Neo.Markdig.Xaml not showing Images
I tried Markdig and Neo.Markdig.Xaml to render markdown files in a WPF application (.NET Core 6). Rendering works really fine (tables, extra emphasis, links,...) but when I add an image to my markdown file, it doesn´t show up. I wonder why, because viewing the exact same file with VSCode looks as expected. So, the path can´t be the issue.
I also tried with MediaLinks and Figures (see below). The below code is pretty close to the example code from neolithos.
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="MarkdigPrototype.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MarkdigPrototype"
            xmlns:md="clr-namespace:Neo.Markdig.Xaml;assembly=Neo.Markdig.Xaml"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer x:Name="flowDocumentViewer">
            <FlowDocumentScrollViewer.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static md:MarkdownXaml.Hyperlink}" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
            </FlowDocumentScrollViewer.CommandBindings>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
namespace MarkdigPrototype
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            currentFileFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\temp\Test.md");

            var content = File.ReadAllText(testPath);
            var doc = MarkdownXaml.ToFlowDocument(content,
                new MarkdownPipelineBuilder()
                .UseXamlSupportedExtensions()
                //.UseMediaLinks()
                //.UseFigures()
                .Build()
            );
            flowDocumentViewer.Document = doc;
        }

        private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Link clicked: {0}", e.Parameter));
    }        
    }
}

Test.md
# Test

![alt text](image.png)

